# libvirt qemu-system-aarch64: Property '.pflash0' not found

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt, uefi

## Goal

I'm currently trying to emulate an Raspberry Pi 3 using QEMU and libvirt (on Arch). I'm (mostly) following [`dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel`'s native guide](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/wiki/Native-emulation-of-Rpi2-or-3-using-Qemu%27s-Raspi2-or-Raspi3-machine).

Just to have a starting (working) place to expand on, I'm using the following which runs fine

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -m 1G \
  -smp 4 \
  -M raspi3 \
  -dtb "/.../bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb" \
  -kernel "/.../kernel8.img" \
  -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" \
  -sd "/.../image.qcow2" \
  -usb -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd \
  -serial stdio
```

Now I'm trying to add it to libvirt. I've got the following XML (which also includes some extras over the QEMU command)

```xml
<domain type="qemu">
  <name>rpi3</name>
  <uuid>...</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://debian.org/debian/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="aarch64" machine="raspi3">hvm</type>
    <kernel>/.../kernel8.img</kernel>
    <cmdline>rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1</cmdline>
    <dtb>/.../bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb</dtb>
    <loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <clock offset="utc"/>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/.../image.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="sda" bus="sd"/>
    </disk>
    <interface type="network">
      <source network="default"/>
      <mac address="..."/>
    </interface>
    <console type="pty"/>
    <input type="mouse" bus="usb"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="usb"/>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc"/>
    <graphics type="spice" port="-1" tlsPort="-1" autoport="yes">
      <gl enable="no"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type="qxl"/>
    </video>
    <controller type="usb" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15"/>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

When I try to add this with virt-manager, I get `qemu-system-aarch64: Property '.pflash0' not found`.

## `virt-install`

I used the following to generate the XML (I went through every flag in `virt-install --help` and tried to map them from the original QEMU command in order):

```sh
sudo virt-install \
  --connect qemu:///system \
  --name rpi3 \
  --memory 2048 \
  --vcpus 4 \
  --import \
  --boot \
    "dtb=/.../bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb,\
kernel=/.../kernel8.img,\
kernel_args=rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" \
  --os-variant debian10 \
  --disk "/.../image.qcow2,bus=virtio" \
  `# --input mouse,bus=usb` \
  `# --input keyboard,bus=usb` \
  `# --serial stdio` \
  --video qxl \
  --virt-type qemu \
  --arch aarch64 \
  --machine raspi3 \
  --print-xml \
  --check path_in_use=off
```

## Checking the UEFI firmware files and related config

This is when using [edk2-avmf AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/?h=edk2-avmf&id=a4ce2eb174355d1916539b66b315a87498968b4f). After installing it, restarting libvirtd and checking virt-manager I have the firmwares showing up:

[image: edk2-avmf firmware list]

The package gives the following message:

```
 1. Uncomment or add/edit these lines in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf 
 
 nvram = [ 
 "/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_CODE.fd:/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_VARS.fd" 
 "/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF32_CODE.fd:/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF32_VARS.fd" 
 ]
 2. systemctl restart libvirtd
```

When I do this (with a trailing comma added on line 2) and restart, libvirtd fails to start. Status:

```
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 788 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 818 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 819 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 787 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 788 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 818 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 819 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:13:02 ... systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
```

When I don't include the trailing comma (as the message suggests), I get the same issue but with a config parse error:

```
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... libvirtd[86519]: hostname: ...
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... libvirtd[86519]: Cannot find 'dmidecode' in path: No such file or directory
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... libvirtd[86519]: configuration file syntax error: /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf:770: expecting a value
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... libvirtd[86519]: Initialisation of QEMU state driver failed: configuration file syntax error: /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf:770: expecting a value
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... libvirtd[86519]: Driver state initialisation failed
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Succeeded.
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 787 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 788 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 818 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov 05 13:16:10 ... systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 819 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
```

I also made my own package that just installs [Debian's UEFI aarch64 package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/qemu-efi-aarch64) and I get the same issue:

```sh
pkgname=qemu-efi-aarch64
pkgver=20181115.85588389
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="A build of EDK II for 64-bit ARM virtual machines"
conflicts=("edk2-avmf")
arch=("any")
url="https://packages.debian.org/buster/qemu-efi-aarch64"
source=("http://ftp.<region>.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/edk2/qemu-efi-aarch64_0~20181115.85588389-3+deb10u1_all.deb")
sha256sums=("08156f2b483958ea0cf3058adacb6ac2b70314d9825ccfe5e431e688024b7200")
package() {
    tar -xf data.tar.xz -C "${pkgdir}"
}
```

## Considering an XML issue

The error suggests that there's a missing item in the XML file but virt-manager with no manual XML editing can trigger this issue and I can't see any other relavent mentions of `pflash` other than the `loader` tag.

## Removing UEFI

The existing QEMU command doesn't even use UEFI (I also double-checked this with `/sys/firmware/efi`, it didn't exist), so I tried to remove it.
When I remove the `loader` tag, I get `unsupported configuration: ACPI requires UEFI on this architecture`.
When I remove `<acpi/>` (as well as the previous change), I get `qemu-system-aarch64: Property '.acpi' not found`.

Comment: I don't think stackexchange is the correct site for this question, as it's about configuring libvirt rather than a question about development. I would suggest unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com (or even raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).
I will point out that "AAVMF" (red hat's chosen name for a build of edk2's ArmVirtPkg QEMU target) is not compatible with the Raspberry Pi - it is for QEMU's 'virt' machine.

Comment: I was unsure about this as a lot of the posts I was finding while troubleshooting were on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Orangutan According to the [libvirt documentation](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/QEMUSwitchToLibvirt#-no-acpi), the flag `-no-acpi` will be set if the `<features>` element does not contain `<acpi>`. This is a problem, since this target has not the ACPI object class property. As a result, QEMU complains that the property cannot be found. I have reported this issue ([#297](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/297)).